# Create a separate template for Hubspot Blog Listing page when on page 2

Tags: blogs, hubspot

I have a Hubspot blog listing template with a hero image, featured blog posts, content listing etc. When I click through to the second page of listings, I would like a template where it doesn't display the hero image or featured posts, it just displays the listings. Is this possible to do within Hubspot?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use HubL in your template and look at the HTTP request page variables, namely the `request.path`. If you know the path of the blog listing page, just use an if statement to only show what you want when the `request.path` matches that exact page.

```
{% if request.path == '/path/to/listing/page' %}
    {# HERO CODE HERE #}
{% endif %}
```

The answer I guess is, yes. But it will require some custom templating. I'm sure you could also use Javascript but that is a bit less elegant.